# Irreducible representations of compact Lie groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I found the following claim in some lecture notes:

*irreducible representations of a compact Lie group must be finite-dimensional*

Is it true or not?  What about compact connected Lie groups?  What about complex rather than real representations?

Comment: It is true, essentially due to H. Weyl, about 100 years ago. Also certainly for compact and connected. Also for complex vector space repns. The basic point is that the _integral_operators_ associated to repns of a compact group are Hilbert-Schmidt, so compact, so have finite-dimensional eigenspaces...

Comment: @paulgarrett: Many thanks!  Why don't you write it as a formal answer and polish it a bit by some link to reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more general assertion holds for compact topological groups, without the assumption of Lie-ness, due to the compactness of Hilbert-Schmidt operators. There are many sources for this, and many on-line. My old notes at 
http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/repns/notes_2014-15/06a_unitary_of_top.pdf
include this sort of result and various further related.

Comment: some of your notes are great (I'm working on the Rankin-Selberg convolution one)

Comment: @user1952009 ... :)

Comment: Many thanks Prof Garrett!  I should also explore your other notes : )